# How to track efficiently working hours in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

Since now collagues filled working hours to issues in GitLab. Each issue belong to a Sprint label, like "Sprint 25", and I calculated total times by looping manually though issues.

Sometimes issue blongs to two Sprint labels, because it had to be reopened. I need only a quick total working hour, but it is quite time consuming to to the sum up.

Is it any better approach to do it? I thought to use milestones instead of Labels. Would you recommend it?

Shall I use GitLab API and write a script to do the calculation?